# Photoshop Ruler Tool, multiple measurements?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, ruler

I have been using Adobe Photoshop for many years, but its the first time for me to wonder about the ruler tool. I use it quite often to make measurements on the image that I am working on, but I know I can only have one measurement at a time, but I am just wondering if it's possible to have the old measurement in place, while adding a new one for direct comparison without having to remember the values. Does anyone know if that can be done?

I am using Photoshop CS5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it can.
Click Analysis>Record Measurements
Now you get a Measurement Log at the bottom of the screen. Use Ruler tool to make a measurement, then click Record measurements in the Log, make a new Ruler tool measurement an so on. You can remove specific columns by clicking them and then clicking the little Trash icon on the right hand side of the Log.